# Check input if it contains upper case and number from interval

Tags: c

For example my input is D44. I'm trying to check if my input from file contains upper case and number from interval <0-99>. Wrong input is for example a456.
I know how to do it with uppercase but thats as far as i got.

```
int main(){
    FILE* file;
    int i = 0;
    char load[50];
    char *upper;
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(load, sizeof load, file) != NULL){
        if (i == 0){
            upper = load;
            if ('A' <= *upper && *upper <= 'Z'){
                printf("Code is: %s", load);
            }
            else{
                printf("Wrong input, try again...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [`strtol()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) to convert a string (`load + 1`) to an integer and check for errors while doing it.

Comment: `if (('A' <= *upper && *upper <= 'Z') || ('a' <= *upper && *upper <= 'z')) {` ... and maybe change the identifier to `first_char` or something (rather than `upper`)

Comment: You might be interested in [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification). Which will work in a portable way, unlike comparing ranges.

Comment: "thats as far as i got" So I can assume that you wrote the shown code. In that case please explain your idea of the purpose of the variable `i`, which I cannot see. Also you have found something of a way to detect upper case letters. What keeps you from adapting that to lower case? You found a way based on "A..Z". The change to "a..z" seems rather obvious. This makes it very unclear what exactly is the problem you have. There are many problems with the shown code, but not how to change it from upper case to lower case detection. So, please write a focused question on the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

To check wether you input is good or not, you must iterate through the entirety of it, which you do not do here.

Moreover, the lib <ctype.h> exists, and in can help you here.

```c
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    FILE* file;
    char load[50];
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int is_ok = 0;

    while(!is_ok) {
        is_ok = 1;
        fgets(load, 50, file);
        for (char *c = load; *c != '\0'; ++c) {
            if (!(isdigit(*c) || isupper(*c))) {
                is_ok = 0;
                break;  // invalid code, no need to check further
            }
        }
    }
}
```